# moderncv two columns in a small part of the page

Tags: two-column, moderncv

I am finishing my CV with `moderncv` package and it has 1.05 pages, something quite annoying. I have already shortened all margins, but I realised my last two sections (languages, personal interests) are wasting almost all the space.

How can I put this last two subsections in two columns, one to each other?

I've tried `minipage` and some other things but it seems that `moderncv` does not use them as it should....

Comment: A blind shot: `\usepackage{multicol}` ... `\begin{multicols}{2}\section{...}...\end{multicols}` ?

Comment: @tohecz Well, it works, but messes up the section header, putting the text in another place and the line in the left

Comment: You can use `\cvlistdoubleitem{Reading}{Athletics}` then you will have `Reading` in one column and the `Athletics` in the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\cvlistdoubleitem{Reading}{Athletics}`to  have Reading in one column and the Athletics in the other. Languages are better be left alone as the current format is more descriptive IMO.

## Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{orange} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[margin=.9in,scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins-- ,scale=0.75
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Harish} % Your first name
\familyname{Kumar} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{Tulu}{Mother tongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Kannada}{Advanced}{Read, Write and Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Advanced}{Read, Write and Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{Hindi}{Advanced}{Read, Write and Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{Sanskrit}{Advanced}{Read, Write and Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{Konkani}{Basic}{Conversationally fluent}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\cvlistdoubleitem{\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11232/harish-kumar}{TeX.SX}}{Chess}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Reading}{Athletics}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Yoga}{Pranayama}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Meditation}{Eating}
\cvlistitem{Not sleeping}  %% This will give only one column
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes! but what i wanted is to have full languages in the left and full interests in the rigth!

Comment: That will spoil aesthetic look IMO. :-)

Comment: I actually changed some stuff before and now fits in one page, but is till it would be interesting. I don't think it will spol the aesthetics a lot if it is only 1/20 part of the page (of course if it is bigger yes). Anyway, It would be interesting to know how to do it!